# handling result if a field is null from database golang mysql

Tags: mysql, go, struct

[the result wanted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S8WrV.png)I have a struct in go

```
type Users struct {
    ID    int    `json:"id"`
    Name  string `json:"name"`
    Age   string `json:"age"`
}
```

I have a mysql database in which some age values are nil so basically to make it dynamic I've been searching for the solution.   "Age string `json:-`" to hide the field if it is returnig the value nil from mysql.
I did two queries

```
   query1: select id,name,age from users where age is not null
   query2: select id,name from users where age is null
```

How can I make it a dynamic query to show the age if exsits else it doesn't don't show it?

Comment: You can't make dynamic columns with in MySQL.

Comment: There is no way to create dynamic struct with different json tags or hiding the value.

Comment: @RaymondNijland i was talking on the result that will be shown as a json value , the table have a row called age  but it has some null values  so i want to control the struct where the age is null it will just show the id and user  else it will show all the fields

Comment: What does JSON have to do with this question, and why are you using `json` tags? Did you mean to use `db` tags?  Or is that an unrelated artifact?

Comment: yeep mr @Flimzy i am working on a rest api with json so i need the tags

Comment: Okay, no problem. It was just unclear whether you thought the tags were related to your question, since you included the [json] tag as well.

Comment: @Medone an alternative solution to Flimzy's answer would be to use `json:"age,omitempty"` tag in Go, and `COALESCE(age, '')` in your sql query. This way you can avoid having to deal with pointers in your Go struct.

Comment: thanks @Flimzy for the solution just to mention if the age is a int  we can replace it sql.NullInt64

Comment: thanks @mkopriva for the additional suggestion it is working also

Comment: @Medone you'll have to convert the int to int64 before you use sql.NullInt64. And if you opt for the alternative you can use `COALESCE(age, 0)` as well.

Comment: @mkopriva i shared the result wanted as a screenshot  titled the result wanted

Comment: @Medone use `,omitempty` in the json tag if you want to avoid `null` properties in your json.

Comment: @Medone Json does not display anything, nor does it create SQL queries. Are you using some kind of 3. party ORM, and you want that ORM to generate certain SQL queries for you based on some submitted Json Input ? Or do you just want to fetch all records in your database, convert them to Json, but have the `Age` property removed for the records where `Age` is NULL ? Or do you want to do something else entirely ? Note  that your question is very moot and unclear, please try to add more details about what you actually need to do.

Comment: @mkopriva i am just new to golang i replaced the string with a pointer string (*string)  as Flimzy suggested but it keeps returning me a null  even though

Comment: @Medone use `,omitempty` like in this example: https://play.golang.org/p/Kb0dAF2mWad

Comment: thank you @nos  it's as you mentioned:" Or do you just want to fetch all records in your database, convert them to Json, but have the Age property removed for the records where Age is NULL "

Comment: @Medone, That's what you need to write in your question then.

Comment: that's what i was looking for @mkopriva thanks for the help

Answer (score 9):

Don't do that.  Instead, use a nil-able type for your `Age` field. `*string` or [`sql.NullString`](https://golang.org/pkg/database/sql/#NullString) would be the most natural choices.  Then just always select it, and the NULL value will be treated properly.

```
type Users struct {
    ID    int     `json:"id"`
    Name  string  `json:"name"`
    Age   *string `json:"age"`
}
```

Then always use:

```
SELECT id, name, age FROM users
```

And when `Age` is NULL in the database, it will be `nil` in Go, and when it's not NULL in the database, it will be a non-nil pointer to a string in Go.

Answer (score 3):

Use `ifnull()` in your query, so that `null` values can be fetched as `''`(string's default value)

```
select id,name,ifnull(age, '') from users;
```

Then use `omitempty` in `json` tag of Age field.

```
type Users struct {
ID    int    `json:"id"`
Name  string `json:"name"`
Age   string `json:"age,omitempty"`
}
```

If default value is fetched in Age, then it will be ignored in json response.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **gonull** (https://github.com/lomsa-dev/gonull):

```
type Users struct {
    ID    gonull.Nullable[int]    `json:"id"`
    Name  gonull.Nullable[string] `json:"name"`
    Age   gonull.Nullable[string] `json:"age,omitempty"`
}
```